# Return false not working for jQuery live

Tags: ajax, jquery

Well this has me well and truly stumped. After searching for the last few hours I still cannot seem to work out where I am going wrong.

I am trying to append an AJAX response to a container when it gets clicked. That works fine but I don't want it to append another object when the elements from the AJAX response also gets clicked.... so:

```
<div id="container">
    <!-- AJAX response to get inserted here, for example -->
    <span id="ajaxResponse"></span>
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$('#container').click(function(e) {
    var current_el = $(this).get(0);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'text.html',
        success: function(data) {
            $(current_el).append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So it works fine but for some reason the click event on #container also fires when I click on the AJAX response span!?

According to jQuery documentation:

> To stop further handlers from
>   executing after one bound using
>   .live(), the handler must return
>   false. Calling .stopPropagation() will
>   not accomplish this.

But unless I am mistaken, I am calling false? :(

Anyone help me out on this?

UPDATED:

So the only way I can get it to work is by updating my code to this:

```
$('#container').live('click', function() {
    var current_el = $(this).get(0);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'text.html',
        success: function(data) { 
            $(current_el).append(data);
        }
    });
});

$('#ajaxResponse').live('click', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

This seems a little messy though... anyone have a better solution?

Comment: the click action propagated from the response to the container. you'll need to unbind the click handler or use a click handler on the new ajax'ed response and use stopPropagation() there

Comment: Unless i am mistaken, you do not use `.live()` .. but still, that part refers to propagation upwards, not downwards..

Comment: Ah yes sorry, my mistake I had copied the version where I didnt use .live - tried both with and without .live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is `live` part you mention in the title of the question ?

It is how the event model works.. If you click on element which does not handle the event, the event will travel up the DOM hierarchy until it finds an element that handles the click (*and stops its propagation..*). Otherwise you would not be able to put an image inside a `<a>` tag and click on it..

You can bind a *canceling* handler on the inner element assuming you have someway to target it..

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'text.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $(current_el).append(data);
        // assuming the returned data from ajax are wrapped in tags
        $(current_el).children().click(function(){ return false;});
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for returning false, i would chain up to click() though :)

Comment: For some reason the return false doesnt work there, it has to be in its own .live funtion (See update in question)

Comment: Thanks Gaby, after playing around with this a little I finally got it to work... not sure why it didnt first time!

Answer (score 0):

I think the return false is referring to something else in this case...
you should try calling stopPropagation() - this should stop the "click" function from propagating down to the ajaxResponse span....

Comment: I had tried .stopPropagation() with no success and after reading the documentation wasn't sure it even worked with .live?

Comment: basically what I think is going on is that the 'click' function is propagating down to the ajaxresponse span... and thats what you want to stop... the return false doesn't really have anything to do with it... If I am wrong here, please correct me. but I have had issues like this before and the propagation was the problem... once I stopped the function from propagatingm the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

One option that you may want to try is switching over to using live(). Essentially, the click event you setup is calling bind(), and the solution you referenced is using live() which is a variation on bind().

For example:

```
$('#container').live("click", function(e) {
    var current_el = $(this).get(0);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'text.html',
        success: function(data) {
            $(current_el).append(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

HTH

Comment: This was the original approach I had but for some reason return false does work when inside the live function...  I have to specifically bind it to the child element, see updated question.